# SSRS - Change Font Colour on Subreport

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a main report that pulls data from our CRM datasource:

-Project No
-Voucher No
-Cheque No

Then I have a subreport that is from a different GP datasource and displays

-Cheque No

These are linked on Voucher No.

The subreport works great, however I need a way to change the font colour if the Subreport "Cheque No" and the Main Report "Cheque No" do not match.

Can I use an expression to check that they match?

Note:  I have tried to use two separate datasets within the same report and use a lookup to pull in the cheque number from GP, however it gives me #error, and I am not sure why.

Comment: Can there be multiple checks for each voucher?

Comment: There should be only one cheque number per voucher.

Comment: In this case lookup functionality sounds better. Can you show your lookup statement?

Comment: I have used this and it returns #error: =lookup(Fields!cbt_voucherno.Value,Fields!IMSVoucherNo.Value,Fields!ChequeNo.Value,"GP")

Comment: Any other thoughts on this Anup?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a parameter to you sub report. That would be evaluated at the SSRS level and appropriate with in the SR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by Using Expression in SSRS Report.
your sub report is linked on [voucher no] you need add one more parameter in your sub report [ChequeNo] and pass it from your main report .
Now you have to right click on your textbox property select Font Select color and Expression of Color

```
=IIF(Parameters!ChequeNo.Value<>Fields!ChequeNo.Value ,"Red","Black")
```

Comment: Hi!  Thank you for this response Arun, I did not get notified this message was here until now.  I have added the parameter to my subreport "ChequeNo", and passed the value from my main report.  I then try to put the expression on colour in my subreport, on the ChequeNo textbox, and it gives me an error message: " The Color expression for the textrun 'ChequeNo.Paragrahs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30452] Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'Microsoft.REportingServices.REportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Parameter' and 'Object'.... I did the same expression you suggested.

Comment: can you add your expression ?

Comment: =IIF(Parameters!ChequeNo<>Fields!ChequeNo.Value,"Red","Black") - I put this on the field in my subreport not in the main report correct?  I couldn't see where I could do that in the main report to call upon the subreport.